# Determining what algorithm MYSQL View is using

Tags: mysql, view

When creating a MySQL View, the algorithm is set to `UNDEFINED`.

How do I see which algorithm MySQL is choosing for the query ?

I tried using "EXPLAIN", but it is not obvious from the results what algorithm was used for the query.

Answer (score 4):

If the view is being processed with the `TEMPTABLE` algorithm, the view will be treated by the optimizer as if it were written as a [subquery in the from clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) (derived table) and should show up in the `EXPLAIN` output as a derived table.

Here's an example of a view that was explicitly defined with the `TEMPTABLE` algorithm.  Two tables show up in the query plan, although this view was just defined as `SELECT *` from a single table.

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   33 | NULL  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | task       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   33 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

When the view is defined with the `UNDEFINED` algorithm, the optimizer...

> prefers `MERGE` over `TEMPTABLE` if possible
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html (also previous versions ~sqlbot)</sup>

Aggregate functions/group by/having, distinct, limit, unions, scalar subqueries, and views that return literals only (not from a table) require `TEMPTABLE` be used... a view without those should be processed as `MERGE` consistently when the algorithm on the view definition is the `UNDEFINED` algorithm.

Because of the nature of the two view algorithms, the only one that can use indexes on the underlying tables to find rows matching the *outer* `WHERE` -- not one inside the view definition, but the one `SELECT ... FROM view WHERE << here >>`.  If the `EXPLAIN` output shows those indexes being used the way you would typically hope, then you're getting `MERGE`.

I generally define views as `MERGE` explictly.  The server will accept and save the definition, but somewhat quietly change it back to `UNDEFINED` and throw a warning if it can't be actually be processed with `MERGE`.

```
mysql> CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE VIEW priority_counts AS SELECT priority_id, COUNT(1) AS quanity FROM task GROUP BY priority_id;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.12 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                       |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1354 | View merge algorithm can't be used here for now (assumed undefined algorithm) |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

`SHOW CREATE VIEW` subsequently shows `ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED`.

Of course, when `MERGE` *is* accepted, it does show in the view definition, as does `TEMPTABLE` when it's explicitly declared that way.

Comment: this explanation is very good, specially the part where you explain which type of queries require TEMPTABLE

Answer (score 0):

For any given view `mydb.myview`, you can do

- `SHOW CREATE VIEW mydb.myview\G`
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.myview\G` (This works because a view appears in [**information_schema.tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) with engine IS NULL)

Nevertheless, you will not see an ALGORITHM defined. Why ?

This was addressed in 2006 in a bug going back to MySQL 5.0.25

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16832

According to the end of that bug report

> The VIEW_DEFINITION column of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA VIEWS table now
>   contains information about the view algorithm.

There were two patches for this:

- http://lists.mysql.com/commits/7561
- http://lists.mysql.com/commits/7564

Apparently, it got lost in the shuffle over the years.

Answer (score 0):

If it's worth something, I have two views in one database.
One of them shows the MERGE algorithm.
The other one shows UNDEFINED algorithm.

The view with the MERGE algorithm is composed of a `SELECT` section followed by a few `LEFT JOIN` sections.

The view with the UNDEFINED algorithm is composed the same way, but it also has `WHERE` and `GROUP` sections.

When I removed the `GROUP` section from the second view, the algorithm changed from UNDEFINED to MERGE.

So the grouping messed with the usage of the MERGE algorithm.

You might also have aggregation or something else in your view declaration, and that might also be the case why the algorithm used is set to UNDEFINED.