# Views with parameters, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, view, parameter

I am working in a PHP application and some "complex" queries are starting to appear in the code. Because of the complexity I am not able to use any ORM and the only resource I have is a plain SQL and PHP MySQL native functions which I don't like.

Without more here is one of the queries I want to convert into a view:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS 'rec',
  CONCAT(
      IF(agreement_list.ActiveFlag, '', 'Agreement is Inactive.'),
      IF(agreement_type.ActiveFlag, '', 'Agreement Type is Inactive.'),
      IF(distributor.ActiveFlag, '', 'License Distributor is InActive.'),
      IF(agreement_distributor.ActiveFlag, '', 'Agreement Distributor is InActive.'),
      IF(customer.ActiveFlag, '', 'Customer is Inactive.'),
      IF(cf_program_level.ActiveFlag, '', 'Program Level is Inactive.')
  ) AS errormessage,
  IF((agreement_list.ActiveFlag + agreement_type.ActiveFlag + distributor.ActiveFlag + agreement_distributor.ActiveFlag + customer.ActiveFlag + cf_program_level.ActiveFlag) < 6, 1, 0 ) AS error
FROM
  license
  JOIN agreement_list ON (agreement_list.AgreementTypeID = license.AgreementTypeID AND agreement_list.CustomerSiteID = license.CustomerSiteID AND agreement_list.Source = license.Source)
  JOIN customer ON (customer.id = license.CustomerSiteID AND license.source = customer.Source)
  JOIN distributor ON (distributor.DistributorID = license.DistributorID AND license.source = distributor.Source)
  JOIN distributor AS agreement_distributor ON (agreement_distributor.DistributorID = agreement_list.DistributorID AND agreement_list.source = agreement_distributor.Source)
  JOIN agreement_type ON (agreement_type.AgreementTypeID = license.AgreementTypeID AND license.source = agreement_type.Source)
  JOIN cf_program_level ON (cf_program_level.CFProgramLevelID = '{$CFProgramLevelID}' AND license.source = cf_program_level.Source)
WHERE
  license.AgreementTypeID = '{$AgreementTypeID}'
  AND license.CustomerSiteID = '{$CustomerSiteID}'
  AND license.Source = '{$Source}'
```

`$CFProgramLevelID, $AgreementTypeID, $CustomerSiteID, $Source` are parameters coming from PHP and that's my only problem. How do I pass a parameter to a view if it's possible?

I am using MySQL 5.6 at the moment.

Comment: What you are asking for is a function returning a table and AFAIK, MySQL does not yet support this. If you want to use a view you must rephrase it so that the parameters are exposed in the select list. However, in my experience, MySQL does not do a great job of pushing predicates inside views, so the performance will likely suffer. AFAIK, your best shot would be a procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Seems simple.  Build the `VIEW` without the last 5 lines.  Then use those 5 lines when you use the `VIEW` as if it were a `TABLE`.

If those `JOINs` are not "many:one", you will get an inflated `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: You'd also need to define the view to `GROUP BY` the columns of interest, so that you could invoke it with an external `WHERE`, and this won't perform well... using aggregate functions [forces a view to use the `TEMPTABLE` algorithm](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54491/11651) instead of `MERGE`, rendering the entire view then filtering for the one row you really wanted.  A stored proc with parameters seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, you can pass parameters to your views in a simple manner by creating a Function to GET your values from Session Variables.
See www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 for the technique.
This is a copy of my create function you may wish to pattern after.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fn_getcase_id()    
RETURNS MEDIUMINT(11)
DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
# see stackoverflow.com/questions/14511760 and read ALL the info TWICE or MORE.  wh 04/13/2017
    RETURN @sv_case_id;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

You will need to create 4 similar FN (one for each variable).

Answer (score 0):

No can do. At least not directly.  Use a procedure that populates a temporary table and reference the table in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**A functional alternative would be to encapsulate the view query in a procedure, with parameter passing. 
This is a simple solution to improve the problem of slow VIEWS with multiple joins queries between multiple tables.**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_QUERY_VIEW_WITH_PARAMETERS`(IN p_having VARCHAR(300))
    COMMENT 'Executes the statement'
BEGIN
  SET @v_having = p_having;
  SET @v_sql=CONCAT('SELECT 
                    id    AS id_emp  ,
                    user  AS emp_name,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    FROM table1
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 
                    idtifier_us    AS id_emp  ,
                    description    AS emp_name,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    FROM table2');
SET @v_sql2 = CONCAT(@v_sql,@v_having);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @v_sql2;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;


CALL `SP_QUERY_VIEW_WITH_PARAMETERS`('having id_emp=63 and emp_name like ''VANDERLEI%'' and created_at between ''2019-05-01'' and ''2019-05-17''  ')
```