# select which algorithm a view is using

Tags: view, mysql-8.0, mariadb-10.4

I have a view in a MariaDB 10.4.13 database that feeds into a database documentation process and gathers data on tables and views used in the database.
Amongst other fields it selects which algorithm each view in the database is using.

A stripped down version of the view (just showing the essential bits is below).

```
SELECT
  `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_NAME` AS `object_name`,
  `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_TYPE` AS `object_type`,
  `information_schema`.`views`.`ALGORITHM` AS algorithm_type
FROM
   `information_schema`.`tables`
LEFT JOIN `information_schema`.`views`
      ON  `information_schema`.`views`.`TABLE_NAME` = `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_NAME`
WHERE `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_TYPE` <> 'SYSTEM VIEW'
```

This works OK on MariaBD and produces something like this

```
  object_name   object_type     algorithm_type 
  ============  ============    ============== 
     V1           VIEW          UNDEFINED  
     V2           VIEW          TEMPTABLE 
     V3           VIEW          MERGE
     V4           VIEW          TEMPTABLE  
     T1           TABLE         NULL
     T2           TABLE         NULL
```

However, my ISP has just changed from MariaDB to MySQL 8.0 and this view's SQL fails on the line

```
`information_schema`.`views`.`ALGORITHM` AS algorithm_type
```

saying `information_schema`.`views`.`ALGORITHM` is unknown.

How should I alter this SQL to make it work in MySQL 8.0 and return the algorithm type (UNDEFINED,  MERGE or TEMPTABLE) in the column `algorithm_type`?

I did look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54481/determining-what-algorithm-mysql-view-is-using) but it didn't really help with the SQL

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  The INFORMATION_SCHEMA VIEWS Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-views-table.html) - no such column. In MySQL ALGORITHM takes three values: MERGE, TEMPTABLE, or UNDEFINED. It can be viewed in SHOW CREATE VIEW Statement.

Comment: Thank you, Yes, I realise that in MySQL 8.0 there is no such column - unlike in MariaDB 10.14 - and that's why I'm getting the error. But if SHOW CREATE VIEW can show it then it's held somewhere. Do you know the correct SELECT ... statement to retrieve it? ie which table / column is it held in?

Comment: ie the sql `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views` shows me many columns in MariaDB, one of which is `ALGORITHM`. The same sql in MySQl 8 shows far fewer columns and while it does show me the `view_definition` that does not contain the algorithm and the SELECT result does not have a separate column for ALGORITHM, unlike MariaDB. But it must be held somewhere in MySQL 8 as SHOW CREATE VIEW can show it (at least for a single view) . So isn't there some sort of SELECT... that will recover it, even if I have to parse it out of some larger text?